# How to Get Scaling-Aware Window Size Using WinAPI

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm creating a C# WPF app which takes screenshots of another program when the user presses a button.

After the user enters the title of the window they want to screenshot, I use the Windows API as following:

```cs
IntPtr window = FindWindowA(null, windowTitle);
IntPtr sourceDeviceContext = GetDC(window);
IntPtr targetDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(sourceDeviceContext);
GetWindowRect(window, out RECT windowSize);
IntPtr bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(
  sourceDeviceContext,
  windowSize.Right - windowSize.Left,
  windowSize.Bottom - windowSize.Top); 
SelectObject(targetDeviceContext, bitmap);
PrintWindow(window, targetDeviceContext, PrintWindowParam.PW_CLIENTONLY);
Image.FromHbitmap(bitmap).Save("C:\\Image.png");
```

However, if the window is on a screen that is using scaling, the image ends up slightly cropped, as GetWindowRect gives logical coordinates, not physical ones.

My question is, how can I find the window size and also take scaling into account?

I've tried to find the scaling using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor with the following code:

```cs
IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(window, MonitorFromWindowParam.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
IntPtr result = GetScaleFactorForMonitor(monitor, out DeviceScaleFactor scale);
```

I tried moving the app between two monitors (one with 100% and one with 125% scaling) and the `IntPtr monitor` value changes appropriately, so the monitor is detected correctly. Furthermore, the `IntPtr result` is `S_OK`, meaning that the function succeeded. However, it always gives me 100% scaling as a response (the integer value of `scale` is `100`) regardless of which monitor I get the scale for.

Is there a reliable way to capture the entire window area of an application, taking scaling into account?

Comment: Make sure your application is itself DPI aware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Simon Mourier's comment on the question, I managed to solve this by enabling DPI awareness in the app itself.

This is done by:

1. Disabling default WPF DPI-awareness by adding this attribute to the assembly:

```cs
[assembly: DisableDpiAwareness]
```

2. Enabling DPI awareness using P/Invoke:

I have a Win32Util that imports these p/invoke functions:

```cs
public enum PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS
{
    Process_DPI_Unaware = 0,
    Process_System_DPI_Aware = 1,
    Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware = 2
}

public enum DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT
{
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = 16,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = 17,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = 18,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 = 34
}

public static class Win32Util
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(int dpiFlag);

    [DllImport("SHCore.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS awareness);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
}
```

And then I use these to enable DPI awareness like this at the start of my app execution:

```cs
// App.xaml.cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DpiAwareness.Enable();
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

```cs
public static class DpiAwareness
{
    public static void Enable()
    {
        // Windows 8.1 added support for per monitor DPI
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(6, 3, 0))
        {
            // Windows 10 creators update added support for per monitor v2
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(10, 0, 15063))
            {
                Win32Util.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext((int)DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT.DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
            }
            else
            {
                Win32Util.SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS.Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Win32Util.SetProcessDPIAware();
        }
    }
}
```